# Amazon SImpleDB Architecture for an user with a friends list

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I am relatively new to database designing. I am currently using amazon SimpleDB to provide my application with information, so far its been relatively good and efficient until just now.
Basically, I keep a registry of users (the items) which have properties related to their accounts on my app.

The problem is that I need a social-like structure, each user must have a list of friends, and a list of pictures that he is allowed to see. Both of these list will keep growing and I just dont know how to handle it in the Amazon SimpleDB Architecture. I thought about having a multi value property, but i fear the size might run out too fast, since the value length is 1024 bytes.

I also thought about having a domain dedicated to the users friends. Having the item name as the userID and using the properties as pages to keep multiple friends, but i think this is totally wrong.

Does anyone have an idea of how to handle this type of architectures in amazon simpleDB? Or should I just change to the traditional database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleDB is a non-relational database. Social data like lists of friends is very much relational data, so SimpleDB is very much the wrong type of database to use for it.

Comment: oh god, does this means that im better off migrating to something else? Could you give me a suggestion please? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Any relational DB would be a better choice than the key-pair style SimpleDB. Also, you really should read a book or something on Relational DB design and Normalization (especially that latter one is exactly what you're asking about).

Comment: Would it be possible to leave the key-pair database design i have so far, since queries like getting the user pictures count, or users email or other fields are easy to handle, and just add a relational database to handle friends and pictures elements? would it be cost effective for example? Ill check the relational DB and normalization as you suggested tho.